# Why does this method need casting?

Tags: java, casting

I've been writing a very basic musicplayer in Java for a school project, and I wanted to add a little sazz by implementing a volume slider. Basically, I read step by step how to do it, and it does work, but there is one element that I frankly don't understand, and that is the

```
(JSlider)event.getSource();
```

method. What I dont't understand is what seems to be casting. Why do I need to cast the event.getSource() to JSlider? And how can I even, since ChangeEvent and JSlider do not have a (to my understanding, at least) sub-class/superclass relationship?

Here is the method in full:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event)
    {
        JSlider source = (JSlider)event.getSource();

        int volume = source.getValue();

        setVolume(volume);
    }
```

Comment: Check out this answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825572/how-do-i-get-from-the-event-object-the-object-on-which-there-was-this-event

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

The method signature is

> public Object getSource()

Since it returns Object, it has to be casted to a JSlider to assign it to a JSlider variable. Everything is a subtype of Object; the compiler does not know that the returned Object is a JSlider.

Answer (score 3):

You don't cast the `event` itself, but you cast the nested `source`.

In your case you get the `source` via:

```
event.getSource();
```

and you cast it, obviously because it's of type that can be casted to `JSlider`. The [getSouce()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) method contract says it returns an `Object` instance, and therefore casting at runtime it will either pass, or will fail and you will receive a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

An event object contains a reference to the component that generated the event. To extract that reference from the event object use:

```
Object getSource()
```

Since the return type of `getSource()` is `Object` (the class at the very top of the class hierarchy) use a type cast with it:

```
// listener method
public void stateChanged( ChangeEvent evt )
{
  JSlider source;

  source = (JSlider)evt.getSource();
  . . . .
}
```

Now you have a reference to the slider that caused the event and you can use any of that slider's methods.

Answer (score 0):

The ChangeEvent contains a reference to a source object (which could be anything that throws a ChangeEvent). In this case you know that it is a JSlider, so you can cast the event-source to JSlider.

Answer (score 0):

This is because an Event can be generated from a variety of sources (Swing Components).

Since this is the case, you need to cast to the appropriate type.

If you didn't cast to JSlider, you could not use the `getValue()` method.