# How to get index of an object with documentListener?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I have 2 lists displayed vertically in a JFrame. Lets say list A is an `ArrayList<CustomTexField>` and list B is an `ArrayList<JLabel>`.

I want to "update" the elements of list B that matches the same index of elements inside list A with the value from the `CustomTextField`.

I've tried adding document listener, but don't know how to calculate the index.

```
@Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        try {

            listB().get(INDEX).setText(e.getDocument().getText(0, e.getDocument().getLength()) + "");

        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I have also created a method inside `CustomTexField` class that saves the index when its created but don't know how to 'read' it from `e.getDocument()`

**EDIT: UPDATED TITLE**

Comment: If you're just asking about how to get the index of an item in an ArrayList, you can use `arrayList.indexOf(itemYouWant)`

Comment: So you want to get the element from list B that corresponds the element being inserted/updated?

Comment: -Yes @Thomas. `indexOf` is not working, because i dont know what `itemIWant`. Depends on which txtfield is edited

Comment: I can't do `listB().inexOf(e.getDocument());` . I want to do something similar, and casting from document gives me error :(

Comment: Can you show full code that adds the document listener ?

Comment: I guess you're adding the listener to each textfield's document anyways so you could just provide that listener with a reference to the corresponding label and update it accordingly. Maintaining 2 separate lists and connecting via index isn't that robust anyways (what if only one list is changed to some programming error etc.?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the index of an item in an arraylist, you can just use the `indexOf` method.

```
int indexOfItem = arrayList.indexOf(itemIWant)
```

This is just how I interpreted your question but I would love clarification.

EDIT: If you're trying to get the object attached to the DocumentListener, you can check out this question: [how to find source component that generated a DocumentEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218731/how-to-find-source-component-that-generated-a-documentevent)

Basically, if you have a DocumentListener for each CustomTextField, you can use the `putProperty` method described in the link to attach itself to it. From there, you can use `getProperty(item)` to find the item. You can do something similar with the index if you want but I believe that since you have an index field in your definition of CustomTextField, just attaching the CustomTextField with the DocumentListener will be enough.

```
//sometime on initalization of the lists
for(CustomTextField field: listA):
    field.getDocument().putProperty("owner", field);

...

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    try {
        CustomTextField field = e.getDocument().getProperty("owner");
        int index = field.getIndex(); //assuming you have a getter method
        listB().get(index).setText(listA.get(index).getText());

    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but how to calculate "INDEX", I dont want to loop through all elements in the list everytime I write something inside a textfield.

Comment: So you're asking about how to get the index of the item that corresponds with the document listener, so you can update it's corresponding JLabel?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want @Jeremy Fisher

Answer (score 0):

I would store all of your `CustomTextField`s in a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the name of the `CustomTextField` and the value is a unique identifier.  Then I would have all of your `Label`s in another `Map<Integer, Label>` where the key is a unique identifier that corresponds to the unique identifier that matches a `CustomTextField`.

Now in your `insertUpdate()` you know which CustomTextField that's getting updated, so get it's unique identifier like:

```
int id = ctfMap.get(customTextField.getName());
```

Take this id and get your Label like this:

```
JLabel label = lblMap.get(id);
```

Set the label's text:

```
label.setText = customTextField.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825572/how-do-i-get-from-the-event-object-the-object-on-which-there-was-this-event) . I also added `focusListener` to the CustomTextFields so when overriding `focusGained` method I can get the Object where the event where called from and cast it to my custom class.

```
private class ListenForDoc implements DocumentListener, FocusListener{
    int index;
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        try {

            listB().get(index).setText(e.getDocument().getText(0, e.getDocument().getLength()));


        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //TO DO

    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}


    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        if(o instanceof CustomTextField) {
            index = ((CustomTextField)o).getIndex();    
        }
        else{
        //HandleError
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

}
```